# I am unable to add a VBA reference to a DLL that I created in C#.net

Tags: c#, excel

I have created some functions in C# that I'd like to use in VBA by referencing a DLL. To do this, I used the VS template for creating class libraries (.Net Framework). I made the assembly COM visible and the build was registered for COM interop.  VS created files myLib.dll and myLib.tlb, and I copied myLib.tlb to \Windows\System32.  In the VBA Tools-Reference I used the Browse button to select and open myLib.tlb. However, myLib does not appear in the list of available references. Can someone identify what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: If your class library was registered for COM Interop, (regsvr32, normally), you should be able to see it's classes if you add a reference to the tlb file. See the build output if anything went wrong during registration for com interop. Do you see a message like "does not contain any types that can be registered for COM Interop." Or anything else? You may need to run VS as administrator for example.

Comment: Also, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You need to provide the source code that fails so that people can reproduce your problem and help.